# Problemas con WorkMail AWS

Tags: aws, mail

como va? Estoy teniendo problemas con la configuracion de un dominio custom en WorkMail, ya que no me dejaba ni enviar y recibir mensajes.
Configure los registros en Route53 y se soluciono el problema de recibir mail, pero sigo sin poder enviar.
En WorkMail/Domains me figura todo verificado menos esta opción.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando envio los mail me arroja este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta seria si es una mala configuracion de DMARC o SMTP, porque todas las guias que me dan de AWS apuntan a crear los registros y configurar DMARC.